# My Numerical keyboard is not working 18.04

Tags: numlock

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed with Gnome Desktop.
My keyboard numerical keyboard is not working even after installing numlockx and checking that is showing ON from Dconf[[image]]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check that the numlock state is showing as 'on'

You can do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then running:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state
```

There should be a return `'on'`

If it is not, then run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state 'on'
```

Check again and confirm that it is showing as `'on'`.

Also make sure to log out and log back in or just do a full reboot to make sure that gnome has taken the new settings.

Comment: kubuntu 20.4 error: `No such schema “org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard”
`

Answer (score 1):

*Can you try to enable the numlock from terminal code is*

`setxkbmap -option keypad:pointerkeys`

*The second solution is in Gnome we must go to System -> Parameters -> Keyboard, then find the section "Mouse buttons" and disable the emulation of mouse from the keyboard.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `dconf` GUI method but, you can open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and try:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard numlock-state 'on'
```

I don't have a problem with my numlock so I'm not sure how to duplicate your situation.

Comment: kubuntu 20.4 error: `No such schema “org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard”
`

Answer (score 0):

go to settings keyboard and make sure your model keyboard is correct. Mine was not, when I changed it to the correct model my number keys work just fine.